# setting text to flash dynamic text fields from asp

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

how can I set the text of dynamic text field from the asp page that loads .SWF file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ASP, can you create/call JavaScript from ASP? If you can, the answer is somewhere along the following lines:

Create a function in your Flash movie that sets the text property of the dynamic text instance. Declare it as external interface, with `ExternalInterface.addCallback`. Check it out [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()).

Then, call your function from JavaScript, like so:

```
document.getElementById('myMovie').myFunction('argument');
```

More on this, [here](http://blog.guya.net/2006/06/19/understanding-flash%E2%80%99s-externalinterface/)

Or, if you only need to modify the text once, when the page loads, you could simply use [FlashVars](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html) and generate the appropriate embed code from your server side script. ASP is server side, right?.. :)